# What is best way to pass data from one call to another in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, javascript-objects

this is of course just a mockup, but you will get an idea.

This is the first call:

```
function getData () {
  $.ajax{( 
     type:'GET',
     url: url,
     success: function (res) {
        // logic 
        // 'res.secret' property value that needs to be passed
        }
    )}
}
```

Now, this gets a set of data, that I need to use for another call with `POST` method later. Let's call it `res.secret`.

So, next call:

```
function postData () {
  $.ajax{( 
     type:'POST',
     url: url + res.secret,
     success: function (res) {
        //logic
        }
    )}
}
```

What is the best way to pass `res.secret` to `postData()` in `url` property? I can save it in html as `data-*`, but don't think that is the best way to do it.

Also, please notice that `postData()` and `getData()` are in separate `.js` files.

Comment: Where is `postData()` called? Saving `res.secret` in a `data` attribute sounds like a fine solution to me.

Comment: But @RoryMcCrossan, won't it be easy accessible by almost everyone then in inspect?

Comment: Yes. But it will be regardless of whether or not you put it in the DOM. The data from any AJAX request can be seen in the console.

Comment: You can defined  a store object (global in app )  and access it from anywhere

Comment: Thanks @RoryMcCrossan, you are right.

Comment: @saeedjalali while that technically would work, globals are a bad thing and should be avoided where possible

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't want to bind to window object.

Comment: I'm presuming there is some time between the get and post data methods?  It's not one right after the other right?  And you may need to store it to pass along to multiple post operations or no?  If you need to keep it locally for some time, you could store it in local/session storage (new to HTML 5).

Comment: @stormec56 it should also be noted that it and everyone in this case, is only the data given to that specific user.

Answer (score 1):

me being old and not loving promises, I would nest it as so; passing the result of the first on success as a parameter to the second:

```
function getData () {
   $.ajax{( 
     type:'GET',
     url: url,
     success: function (res) {
        postData(res.secret);
     }
   )}
}

function postData (theSecret) {
  $.ajax{( 
    type:'POST',
    url: url + theSecret,
    success: function (res) {
      //logic
    }
  )}
}
```

this causes sequential and conditional execution.

Comment: Can't, calls are in separate files.

Comment: @stormec56 I missed that part, but it should not matter as long as they are in the same namespace.

Comment: @stormec56 okay I get the problem. I'm on my phone but if I remember I'll type something up when I get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

It's an ideal case for using promises. Here is how I'd right it in ES6 with async/await

```
(async () => {

    // result1 awaits for GET request to be resolved
    var result1 = await fetch(url);
    // then you pass your 'secret' from result1 to your next POST call
    var result2 = await fetch(`${url}${result1.secret}`, {method: 'post'});

})();;
```

Comment: This is assuming that `postData()` is called immediately after `getData()` completes - which wouldn't appear to be so given the OP's example case.

Comment: I see now, thought you'd want them to happen in sequence. In this case you can store it somewhere in a state of some sorts